# Return values for attributes and display those values under each attribute (php codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is it possible to return the values for the attributes selected under the name of the attributes so the values could be displayed under the attribute they belong to?

The array

```
Array ( [product_id] => 41 [attributes] => Array ( [0] => Colour [1] => Size )
```

This is what I've tried
The Controller

```
$data2['product_id'] = $this->input->post('id');
$data2['attributes'] = $this->input->post('pAttr');
$data2['values'] = $this->inventory_model->get_attribute_values($data2);
$this->load->view('add_attr_value_view', $data2);
```

The Model

```
// this will get values for the attributes in the array    
extract($data2);

$this->db->select('attribute_value.value');
$this->db->from('attribute_value');
$this->db->join('attributes', 'attributes.id = attribute_value.attribute_id');
$this->db->where_in('attributes.attribute', $attributes);
$result = $this->db->get();

for($i = 0; $i < count($attributes); $i++) {
    foreach($result->result() as $row) {
        $entry = array();
        $entry[$attributes] = $row->value;

        $data[] = $entry;
    }
}
return $data;
```

The View

```
foreach ($attributes as $res) 
{
    echo    "<br />" ;
    echo $res['attributes'];
    echo    "<br />" ;

    foreach ($values as $res)
    {
        $val = $res['values'];
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='aVal[]' value='$val'>" .$val. "<br />" ;
    }
}
```

attributes table

```
____________________
|  id  | attribute |
--------------------
|  1   |  Colour   |
|  2   |  Size     |
```

attribute_value table

```
______________________________
|  id  | attribute_id | value |
-------------------------------
|  1   |       1      | Red   |
|  2   |       1      | Blue  |
```

product_attr_value table

```
___________________________________________
|  id  | product_id   | attribute | value  |
--------------------------------------------
|  1   |       21     | Colour    | Red    |
|  2   |       21     | Size      | Medium |
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve

```
Colour  
checkbox Red  
checkbox Blue 
.  
.  

Size  
checkbox Small  
.  
.
```

Comment: Where is `$values` defined in the view? Also what do the `foreach` loops output?

Comment: you code is unclear. `for` loop running with attributes but `foreach` running  $result. Confused. Can you add full code?

Comment: @VincentWilkie, $values is the array key from $data2['values'] in the controller, but I don't know if I need to change it to $attributes instead because of $entry[$attributes] = $row->value; The foreach loop is supposed to output the values under the attributes

Comment: @kumar_v, full code added

Comment: You'll have to provide your database structure for this.

Comment: in your product_attr_value table you should be storing ids instead of values, your current setup doesn't make sense.